# expo-av stops unexpectedly inside interval

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

I'm new to React-native, and I experience a strange behavior using `Audio` from `expo-av`.
I'm trying to make an audio looping infinitely every 1000ms. I don't see any delay option so I'm setting an interval. The loop works fine but, the weird thing, is I only get 39 audio play. Very consistently, 39 everytime, and then the audio stops playing, though the interval keeps running (I see logs being displayed). Here's the code:

```
import audioFile from "./assets/audios/sound.mp3";

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(async () => {
      const audioSource = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(audioFile);
      await audioSource.sound.playAsync();
      console.log("Inside interval");
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

Anyone knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I actually found the solution with the help of [this expo issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1873#issuecomment-636236483). It seems that playing the same audio file quickly multiple times kinda break it at some point. The trick is to unload it from time to time using the `unloadAsync()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of unloading sound everytime, you can reuse it by storing it in memory.

Here's the working solution.

```js
const loadedSounds: Record<string, AV.Audio.Sound> = {};

export const playSound = async (
  sound: string,
  volume = 1
) => {
  let soundObject = loadedSounds[sound];

  if (soundObject) {
    console.log("Replaying sound", sound);
    await soundObject.setVolumeAsync(volume);
    await soundObject.replayAsync();
    return soundObject;
  }

  const music = SoundLibrary[sound];
  if (!music) return;

  soundObject = new AV.Audio.Sound();
  await soundObject.loadAsync(music);
  await soundObject.setVolumeAsync(volume);
  await soundObject.playAsync();
  loadedSounds[sound] = soundObject;
  return soundObject;
};
```